# How to avoid border gap in outside corner between divs

Tags: html, css, border

I am using borders to draw "walls" between some divs, but not others. I am adding a solid border in each div in order to form a divider. Currently I have something that looks like this:

[image: corner gap]

A and B have right/left borders set, and A/C have bottom/top borders set. D has no borders.

Current CSS: [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzzpYG)

```
.a {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-right: 10px solid black;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}
.b {
   background-color: cyan;
   border-left: 10px solid black;
}
.c {
  background-color: lightpink;
  border-top: 10px solid black;
}
.d{
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.a, .b, .c, .d {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

I'd really like to eliminate the little notch in the corder of D. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
.d {
  position: relative;
}

.d:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```css
 .a {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-right: 10px solid black;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}

.b {
   background-color: cyan;
   border-left: 10px solid black;
}

.c {
  background-color: lightpink;
  border-top: 10px solid black;
}

.d {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.a, .b, .c, .d {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

}

.d {
  position: relative;
}

.d:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0;

}
```

```html
 <div>
     <div class='a'>a</div>
     <div class='b'>b</div>
</div>
<div style='clear:both;'>
     <div class='c'>c</div>
     <div class='d'>d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! I find it easier to put the pseudo element on c, but this works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
.a {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-right: 10px solid black;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}
.b {
   background-color: cyan;
   border-left: 10px solid black;
}
.c {
  background-color: lightpink;
   border-top: 10px solid black;
}
.d{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
}
.a, .b, .c, .d {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
.d > span{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height :10px;
  background-color: black;
  top:-10px;
  left: 0;
}
```

>

```
<div>
  <div class='a'>a</div>
  <div class='b'>b</div>
</div>
<div style='clear:both;'>
  <div class='c'>c</div>
  <div class='d'><span></span>d</div>
</div>
```

```css
.a {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-right: 10px solid black;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}
.b {
   background-color: cyan;
   border-left: 10px solid black;
}
.c {
  background-color: lightpink;
   border-top: 10px solid black;
}
.d{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
}
.a, .b, .c, .d {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}


.d > span{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height :10px;
  background-color: black;
  top:-10px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='a'>a</div>
  <div class='b'>b</div>
</div>
<div style='clear:both;'>
  <div class='c'>c</div>
  <div class='d'><span></span>d</div>
</div>
```

It's my answer, but it's just a trick.

I'm sorry. Actually, I can't find another better solution.